# How can I eliminate non fatal PHP warnings from my error log file

Tags: php, suppress-warnings

This is in regard to a shared web hosting plan, so I only have limited control over the server. I do occasionally write PHP modules to assist various tasks, and so I have edited my PHP.INI file to direct all errors to a single log file, which I can download and examine as needed. Most errors or warnings come with a time stamp, a description of the problem, a line number in the PHP file, and the name of the file. But lately I've been getting occasion warnings like the below...

`[06-Jun-2023 21:39:13 America/New_York] PHP Warning: Cannot load module 'memcached' because required module 'igbinary' is not loaded in Unknown on line 0`

I've seen people complain about this exact warning and have seen a lot of suggestions, but they are mostly for people running their own server. As I mentioned, I'm on a low cost shared hosting plan so my control is limited. And since none of my PHP scripts are misbehaving, tracking this warning down may not be worth my effort or time (correct me if I'm wrong). It could be caused by some nefarious individual who is hitting one of my PHP scripts file trying to do something I'm not allowing. I have original music for example, which you can only access via a PHP script using proper credentials, and my music specific logs always show plenty of failed attempts.

But anyway, since the warnings are not negatively affecting any of my PHP scripts, is there anything I can change in my PHP.INI file to suppress them? my error_reporting is currently set as follows...

`error_reporting = E_ALL & ~E_DEPRECATED & ~E_STRICT`

Should I add "& ~E_CORE_WARNING" or possibly "~E_WARNING" ? I guess I could experiment, but I'd hate to accidentally suppress a warning actually caused by something in one of my scripts. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I would just contact your host and tell them the error you are getting, see if they can fix it properly before trying to find a workaround.

Comment: If you want more control, an Amazon Web Services LightSail linux server with the free, limited version of Plesk costs around $8 a month, though probably more if you have heavy traffic and many large file downloads.

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton I likely will try that route, but I'd still like to know if I can suppress them.

Comment: @Randy Suppressing warnings and errors is generally considered bad practice. I don't know if it's possible in this case or not, but you should try to keep that in mind. No reason to suppress it if your host fixes it.